# Discrepancy between 'views preview' and actual rendered view with flags

Tags: views, flags

I have some flags for the states Complete / Incomplete. There are 5 of these flags attached to a content type 'client goals'. The two roles, Editor and Admin are able to toggle these states through different views.

When I have the two different views open on multiple screens, the toggle immediately toggles in the 'views preview' and then if I refresh the preview of the other role (in views), this also reflects the changes that were made in the other view.

My problem is that when I actually display this view on the front-end of my site, the toggled alterations are not 'saved' and thus not reflected in the view. There seems to be a disconnect therefore with the display in views and the display on the site.

I was hoping that someone might be able to help me out working out why the toggles are not saving in each case and what the disconnect might be?

Thanks for your help.

I'm not allowed to post images due to my noob nature - but here are some links to the images

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5nWEQpoRUfuVkp5bHVGRlI0T2s/edit

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5nWEQpoRUfuT0dxVkxMREx4Y0E/edit

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5nWEQpoRUfuOTUtamZjeGJEY2M/edit

Comment: Turns out that I had not set the scope of the flag to 'Global' meaning that each user was altering their own version of the flag. I set it to global and it all works as expected. I then needed to set permissions on the view such that only the creator of the content could see it.